# How to convert date string with timezone to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I need to compare two date string and for that, I need to convert the date string to datetime object. An example of a date string is "2015-08-23T03:36:30-05:00". I am assuming "-05:00" is the timezone string. I could to convert the string to datetime using below approach:

```
import datetime

str = '2015-08-23T03:36:30-05:00'

datetime.datetime.strptime(str,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%f:00")
```

[image]

I can see the value of `microsecond` as `50000` which seems wrong to me as the -5:00 value is the timezone. What is the correct way to parse as I will be comparing two datetimes?

Comment: `%f` is the parser directive for parsing the microseconds part of the timestamp. The UTC offset directive is `%z`, but it uses a format without colon. So, if you can adjust the source format, you can go with the standard directives. Otherwise, you might have to come up with a custom regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `%z` to parse timezone info:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 23, 3, 36, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)))
```

Then, if you want to convert this datetime to UTC (which I assume is your goal since you say you want to compare datetimes), you could use `astimezone` method:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 23, 8, 36, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Back in string format:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").astimezone(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2015-08-23 08:36:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the initial time is in the wrong time zone, you can reverse to UTC time this way:

```
dt = '20230206 04:00:00 Asia/Muscat'
dateTime = dt[0:17]`
timeZone = dt[18:]
dateTimeDt = datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
timeDiff = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timeZone)).strftime('%z')
dateTimeUTC = dateTimeDt - timedelta(hours=int(timeDiff)/100)

print('Initial local time : ',dateTime)
print('UTC time: ',dateTimeUTC)
```